# & in print function -- python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, and-operator

print(2 & 3)

I came across a problem statement in one of my technical assessments, I can't understand the usecase of this '&' operator. Can anyone help me, with how this & operator work in python3

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Answer (score 1):

`&` is a bitwise operator, so this is simply where the binary bits line up between `2` and `3`
https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

```
>>> bin(2)
'0b10'
>>> bin(3)
'0b11'
>>> int("0b10", base=2)  # binary string -> int (base10)
2
```

Here's an example with some bigger numbers

```
>>> bin(12)
'0b1100'
>>> bin(10)
'0b1010'
>>> 12&10
8
>>> bin(8)
'0b1000'
>>> bin(~8)  # NOTE 8 is signed
'-0b1001'
>>> 8&-8
8
```